# PHP math '+' action not working well

Tags: php, math

```
$btc = get_user_balance_btc($_SESSION['btc_uid']);
$ltc = ltc_get_user_balance_usd($_SESSION['btc_uid']);
$count = ($ltc + $btc);
```

When I print btc its printing well 50$ ,when i print LTC its printing well 8$ , but when I am printing the count its printing `0.0013456` I just did a '+' action.

Comment: Please format the code so that it is readable

Comment: One would presume that `get_user_balance_btc()` returns the number of BTC while `ltc_get_user_balance_usd()` returns the value of the LTC balance in USD. It doesn't make any sense to add those two numbers together.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one or both of the variables are strings instead of floats. Try this:

```
$count = ( (float)$ltc + (float)$btc );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$count = (int)$ltc + (int)$btc;
```

Comment: That won't work, as an integer does not accept decimal numbers.